# Can I update value in a ListView?

Tags: c#, winforms, listview

I'm adding values to a `ListView` using this:

```
ListViewItem item1 = new ListViewItem("s1");
item1.SubItems.Add("s2");

ListViewItem item2 = new ListViewItem("s3");
item2.SubItems.Add("s4");

ListViewItem item3 = new ListViewItem("s5");
item3.SubItems.Add("s6");

listView1.Items.AddRange(new ListViewItem[] { item1, item2, item3 });
```

Now I want to change say, `s2` to `s2_baa`. I'm finding a bit difficult to use `ListView`...  is it possible? if so, how can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the Text Property of SubItem

```
ListViewItem lvi = listView1.FindItemWithText("s2");
if (lvi != null)
{
    lvi.SubItems[0].Text = "s2_baa";
}
```